# Change linechart color when combobox selected

Tags: c#, colors, combobox, linechart

Here is my code 
I want to change the line chart color based on user choosing combobox.
How I can type in comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged??
Thank you for your help. Really appreciate !!

```
private void showGraph(List<double> closeList)
{
    List<double> top;
    List<double> medium;
    List<double> bottom;
    //some calculation to find out top, medium, bottom by using closeList
    //linechart is drawing here
}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    List<double> closeList;  
    showGraph(closeList);
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Yellow")
    {

    }

    else if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Red")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done using following code :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Yellow")
    {
         chart.Series["series1"].Points[0].Color = Color.Yellow;
    }

    else if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Red")
   {
         chart.Series["series1"].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
   }
}
```